# Do I need to keep refresh Facebook token in my App

Tags: android

I am creating a mobile app that uses Facebook login

When the user logs in with Facebook , I receive his name email id and access token

Then I take them to my server, If this is the first time of login for this ID I create a new user from the provided information after validating token with Facebook API, then I generate a token on my server.

And If it is an existing user , after validating with Facebook, I give him a token on my server.

Considering I’ve got all information I need from Facebook

Do I need to keep refreshing Facebook token and Why?

Help would be appreciated and Thanks

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401563/does-a-facebook-applications-access-token-expire

Comment: Since you are using facebook just for login, there is no need to refresh the facebook token.

Comment: OK, Thank You all